# How to pass exception to the constructor?

Tags: java

I search around but have no idea how to do this

```
public class NoUserException extends Exception {
     public NoUserException(int id, Throwable cause){
          super("User" +id + " not found");
     }
}

public class User {
    public int getUserID(int id) throws NoUserException{
        try{
            throw new NoSuchUserException(id, throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException here);
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

        }
        return id;
    }
}
```

How can I pass `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` to the constructor? I really don't know how to do this.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish? It is unclear to me from reading the title and the code.

Comment: `super("User +id + " not found");` how can this even compile

Comment: Something tells me you have a deeper design flaw.

Comment: you mean something like `throw new NoUserException(id,e)` ?

Comment: All exceptions are also objects of some Throwable instance,just pass the Throwable instance.I am not sure what you are trying to acheive but dont use throw keyword

Comment: my question is that how do pass exception to the constructor?

Comment: I think the throw here could be for demonstration purposes like "this exception is thrown here"

Comment: So I need to pass in the user id and ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException as the arguments to NoUserException().

Comment: `throw`  can't be used in argument

Comment: If you want to catch `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and throw `NoUserException` with the caught exception as a cause, then you should put `throw new NoUserException(id, e)` in the `catch` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the constructor in the exception - you give the cause into the constructor of the super class Exception:

```
public class FooException extends Exception
{

    public FooException( int id, Throwable cause )
    {
        super( "user " + id + " not found", cause );

    }

}
```

In your code you could use this like this:

```
public void method( int id ) throws FooException
{
    try
    {
        someMethodThatThrows();
    }
    catch ( ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e )
    {
        throw new FooException( id, e );
    }
}

private void someMethodThatThrows()
{
    throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
}
```

The try block "looks" at every Exception thrown and if it is an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` it jumps into the catch block - there you can throw your own exception with the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as cause.

Answer (score 0):

throw new NoSuchUserException(id, new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException());

Do you mean that?